# Is it normal for EF 24-105/4L IS to autofocus when switched to manual focus?

Tags: lens, canon, autofocus, manual-focus

I'm using a Canon 6D mark II. I recently got a Canon EF 24-105mm f/4L. I wanted to try using manual focus, so I switched the lens to manual focus, but it keeps auto focusing when I half press shutter button. I have reset my settings, but it still keeps doing the same thing. Is this normal? Could there be a problem with my lens or camera?

Comment: I don't have the lens you have, but with an EF-S 18-135/3.5-5.6 IS USM, when switched to AF, it can still manual focus using manual focus override. When switched to MF, it can still autofocus using back button autofocus. Have never had it autofocus in MF mode with half-shutter press though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , i know that you can mf when it is switched to af but what i'm confused at is that when switching to mf , auto focus is not supposed to work with half press shutter , i'm really not sure and i need to be before i contact the seller for this problel .

Comment: Hmmm...no, setting to MF should disable AF entirely. Just to confirm, you are using the right switch, right (not The IS switch)?

Comment: @xiota That works? It does not with a 5D Mark III and the 24-105mm f/4L (just tried it) and I really haven't heard of this 'workaround' before...interesting!

Comment: Yes i'm pretty sure i switched the af -mf not the is switch , i'm really confused , some ppl told me that it might be some settings with your camera but i don't think so .

Comment: @flolio , i guess there is a problem in ly lens because it worked as it should with your 5dm3 .

Comment: @Kidd Not a solution: You can always use manual override with this lens, so just rotate the focus-ring at any point and AF should stop. Maybe a solution: Have you tried cleaning the lens's contacts? As far as I have heard, erasers should work well for that - do not use static cloths or aggressive chemicals!

Comment: @flolilo , no i'm not gonna touch it , i guess i got scammed , i'll contact the seller tomorrow to get my money back , shame on him , he said it works flawlessely .

Comment: @flolilo - Apparently, Canon gear does weird stuff when I use it.

Comment: Have you tried detaching and reattaching the lens? My EF/EF-S lenses are sometimes glitchy until re-mounted. Maybe it's when I've detached them to keep the aperture stopped down. Don't know if camera on/off makes a difference. Last time it happened, I remounted the lens with the camera on.

Comment: You should try the lens with a different body and a different known-working lens with the new body. The new camera may simply control lenses differently from how you expect.

Answer (score 3):

Are you certain that the camera actually changed focus while set to MF? With an IS lens on the camera, you’ll often hear a noise when you half-press the shutter release, but that noise is the image stabilizer kicking in, not the AF system.

Try setting the lens to MF with IS switched off. This time you shouldn’t hear or see anything when you half-press the shutter release.

Comment: I tried that , it still focuses , anyway , i got my money back from the seller and he admited the issue after he tried it and i got another one in better condition , it works perfectely.

Answer (score 1):

If the switch is set to MF and the AF motor is engaging there is something wrong with the lens.

Depending on:

- The specific lens model and how much it is worth versus how much it will cost to have it repaired
- Whether it is still covered under warranty
- Whether it might have been damaged in a way that would preclude warranty coverage even during the warranty period
- Whether you are willing to use 'back button' AF to work around the issue

You can either decide to have the lens repaired, you can decide to replace the lens, or you can decide to use the lens as is and work around the problem using custom camera settings to separate AF from the shutter button half press using 'back button focus'. For Canon cameras that do not have an 'AF-ON' button, you can use the menu to set the 'AE-Lock' button, the one with the little six sided star [*] next to it, to act as an 'AF-ON' button.

I recently encountered an EF 85mm f/1.8 that needed some internal cleaning (well beyond dust that does not affect the image). In the process of disassembly/reassembly the plastic prong of the actual electrical switch soldered to the lens' main circuit board beneath the external AF/MF switch was damaged. It can be moved, but the lens must be partially taken apart to do so. The prong is no longer long enough to engage the guides on the back of the external switch that sits on top of it. I chose to set it to AF and reassemble the lens. Since I use back-button AF most of the time anyway, if I want to manually focus the lens, I only need to not press the 'AF-ON' button before taking the photo. The EF 50mm f/1.4, EF 85mm f/1.8, and EF 100mm f/2 all use the same basic construction including the same less than elegant interface between the external mechanical switch on the lens' exterior and the actual electrical switch underneath it that is directly soldered to the main PCB. It's very easy to damage the switch when assembling the lens.

The switch on the EF 24-105mm f/4L IS is different, but my guess is that the AF/MF switch has been damaged and the lens is stuck in AF, regardless of the position of the external switch.